# XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:application/pdf;base64, ..... Cross > origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: android-webview, pdf.js

I am trying to load a base64 String as parameter when calling  the URL in the mWebView.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=data:application/pdf;base64," + pdfString);
```

to render it as PDF file with the help of the PDF.js. The `pdfString` is the converted PDF to base64 String.

When debugging the webView in Chrome -->  the delevopler tool --> remote device --> inspect -->
I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:application/pdf;base64, ..... Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient());

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);


    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/income_tax_return.pdf";
    File file = new File(path);
    int size = (int) file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    try {
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String pdfString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);


   mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=data:application/pdf;base64," + pdfString);


}
```

Comment: I have found out that the code works on Android (version 5.0.1 API 21) and not version 4.4.4 API 19. Does one know the reason?

Comment: to save memory, load empty viewer `mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=")` and wait for viewer to be fully loaded and exec `mWebView.evaluateJavascript("PDFViewerApplication.open(new Uint8Array([" + bytesStr + "]))");`. Notice that base64 is very memory hungry.